# Can a function return a representation of what was passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

Example for clarity:

```
def foo(arg1):
   <function goes here>

x = 5
foo(x > 4)

# foo() should return "x > 4" here.
# I do not want it to return the value, True.
```

It's for a custom file debugger and I was wondering if it was a possibility.
If not, is there a way for a variable outside of a function's scope be passed into it? (the actual variable, *not its value.*)

Comment: No, it's not possible. The function just receives the value, not the original expression.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable references.

Comment: Remember, Python compiles to byte code. When the script is running, there's no `x > 4` anywhere. There's a series of byte codes that load the variable`x`, loads `4`, then calls the `>` operator.

Comment: The term `x>4` gets evaluated before the result is passed to the function. However, complex data types will be passed by reference (Lists, ...)

Comment: This will be difficult. You need to know some built-in libraries of Python.

Comment: @Nechoj *All* values are passed the same. This has nothing to do with call-by-value, call-by-reference, or call-by-name (which is as good a name as any for Python's semantics).

Comment: @chepner That is simply wrong. Write a test program, pass an integer variable, pass a list variable and compare.

Comment: That has to do with mutability, not how the argument is passed. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.